# AS400 - Crear CSV UTF8 a partir de fichero físico con CCSID no UTF8

Tags: as400

Quiero generar un csv en IFS a partir de un PF-DTA con diversos CCSID (dependiendo de la máquina puede ser 37, 1145 o 65535. Aunque no descarto otros).
El problema son los acentos y las letras especiales como 'ç' o 'ñ' o 'ĉ' que aparecen cambiadas por símbolos al no ser mapeadas.

Este fichero se genera por batch en un Job del sistema.

¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar el CCSID y que transforme correctamente esos caracteres, ya sea por comando o programa RPG o CLP?

Un saludo.